# OpenCV code causes leaks of UIImages

Tags: ios, opencv, memory-management, uiimage

I'm doing live video processing on iOS using OpenCV, without using `CvVideoCamera`. My app is crashing due to Memory Pressure.

The native iOS camera calls this function every time a frame is captured:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    //convert the frame to a UIImage:
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

    //convert the UIImage to a Mat:
    Mat srcMat = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

    //Process the Mat:
    Mat dst, cdst;
    Canny(srcMat, dst, 50, 200, 3);
    cvtColor(dst, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
}
```

The app crashes about 15 seconds later due to memory pressure.

I'm using [Apple's code for `imageFromSampleBuffer:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html), and [OpenCV's code for `cvMatFromUIImage`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/image_manipulation/image_manipulation.html). Yes, I'm using ARC.

I profiled the app with the Allocations Instrument, and found that the crash is due to huge numbers of `UIImage` being created and never released. After some investigation, I found that the call to `Canny()` is responsible for that, because `UIImage` objects don't leak when the call to `Canny()` is commented out.

Why would the call to Canny make `UIImage` objects stay in memory?

Comment: I was under the impression that `UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];` doesn't allocate dynamic memory. Doesn't it just creates a pointer to an existing memory location? But if you are right and that is truly happening, rest assured that it shouldn't be a pointer. You can make the fix yourself. What version of OpenCV is this?

Comment: Hi @karphillip. This is OpenCV 2.4.9. `imageFromSampleBuffer` just transforms a `CMSampleBufferRef` into a `UIImage`. As you can see from [its code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html), it turns it into a Quartz Image which it then feeds to `+[UIImage imageWithCGImage:]` thereby allocating a new `UIImage`. It does clean up the memory after itself. But the leak is coming from the call to `Canny()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

    CFRetain(sampleBuffer);

    dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("my.dispatch.q", 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue,
    ^{
        //convert the frame to a UIImage:
        UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

        //convert the UIImage to a Mat:
        Mat srcMat = [self cvMatFromUIImage:image];

        //Process the Mat:
        Mat dst, cdst;
        Canny(srcMat, dst, 50, 200, 3);
        cvtColor(dst, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
    });
}
```